# Visualizing Instagram Travel photo locations on a Map

Tags: maps, photography

I uploaded many of my travel pictures on Instagram and tagged their location. Unfortunately, [Instagram got rid of their photo map](https://www.theverge.com/2016/9/6/12817340/instagram-photo-map-removals). I loved this feature. There are many third party developers trying offering this feature. All I tried so far are either super expensive or do not work properly. 
Is there a (in the best case free or at least cheap) good website or an app that offers this feature?

I have crossposted the question at:

- [Photo stackexchange](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/115171/visualizing-instagram-travel-photo-locations-on-a-map)

Comment: I was very sad that day it left the app :(

Comment: If you have OnePlus mobile, their stock gallery app has very similar section called "Places" in Explore tab. But it uses only geotagged photos and there is no option to edit the geotag. Adobe lightroom also has geotaging feature but it is paid.

Answer (score 2):

Google have now included a map feature in the latest version of Google Photos for Android and iOS.

As I type this it's just started rolling out worldwide.

[Review](https://www.theverge.com/2020/6/25/21301932/google-photos-redesign-map-view-memories-search)

I've tried it on my Android phone - it works pretty well.

Get it from [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.photos), or the App Store - it's free!